# react.js render components at different locations

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started using react.js and have a (hopefully) simple question about the tutorial:
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

I want to render the "CommentForm" at a different position in my html than the "CommentList"

I tried the following:

```
React.renderComponent(
   <CommentBox data={data} />,
    document.getElementById('comentBox')
);

React.renderComponent(
   <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={CommentBox.handleCommentSubmit} />,
    document.getElementById('commentForm')
);
```

But this doesn't work.
What is the best solution to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CommentBox` is a type. When you use JSX to create a JSX-tag with it like `<CommentBox>` then you're creating an instance of the type. This means that `CommentBox.handleCommentSubmit()` is a function on the type, and it won't work on the instance. So you would need to do `var box = <CommentBox data={data} />; box.handleCommentSubmit()` but...

The best way to solve the communication between the two separated components is, to put a callback manager between them, something like an event bus. Inside `CommentBox` you would start to subscribe/listen to events using that event bus, and those events would be dispatched from within `CommentForm` using the same event bus.

The key is to put that callback logic inside the components, and not try to use properties to pass them. Properties of root React components (the `renderComponent` ones) should not be callbacks.

Have you read about Facebook's Flux? It's kind of what I described above. Give RefluxJS a try: https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs

Answer (score 2):

[`React.renderComponent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendercomponent) returns a reference to the component. For the sake of getting the example working, keep that reference in a variable and pass it to the `CommentForm` instance:

```
var commentBox = React.renderComponent(
   <CommentBox data={data} />,
    document.getElementById('commentBox')
);

React.renderComponent(
   <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={commentBox.handleCommentSubmit} />,
    document.getElementById('commentForm')
);
```

As mentioned by @Rygu, an event bus might be appropriate for components that don't have a parent-child relationship as suggested in React's [communication between components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) doc.